# ASP.NET MVC 4 jQuery autocomplete problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am new to MVC and trying to get autocomplete working on a textbox to return suggested MemberNames. I have two problems (Problem1 - getting the user's initial text characters into the controller, and Problem2 - getting returned controller list of names to appear below the text box).

View:

```
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({ source: '@Url.Action("MemberList", "Grievances", new { autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").val() })' });
    });     
    </script>
}
...
<input id="autocomplete">
```

Problem1 - In the above View, if I do not put in the 3rd parameter for @Url.Action, my controller receives null for parameter value (even though a bunch of websites tell me autocomplete automatically binds this value, it's not doing it).

If I put in a hardcode for the 3rd parameter, like this:

```
new { autocomplete = "ead" }
```

then the controller receives "ead" as parameter value. If I put in the code as it is in the code block above, the website errors out, complaining of "Unexpected character '$'" in the 3rd parameter.

Question1 - How can I pass the value of the autocomplete text box into the controller?

Problem2 - Here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult MemberList(string autocomplete)
{
var memberNames = (from p in context.Members
                   where p.MemberName.Contains(autocomplete)
                   select p.MemberName).Distinct().Take(10);
string content = string.Join<string>("\n", memberNames);
return Content(content);
}
```

When I hard code a value (like 'ead') into the 3rd parameter in the view above, then I get the value here in the controller. The Controller retrieves a list of appropriate records from the database, and I return it back to the View. However, nothing shows up under the text box. I do have the necessary JavaScript and CSS files included in the View; if I hard code a list of values, they do show up appropriately under the text box. It's only the controller that it can't get the results from.

Question2 - How do I get the controller to return a list of values so the autocomplete text box will show them?

Your help with these 2 problems is greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm just spinning my wheels in the mud getting autocomplete to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q1

You are mixing jQuery (`$("#autocomplete").val()`) and Razor (`@Url.Action("MemberList", ...`) together in the following line. Razor runs on Server whereas jQuery executes on client hence the error.

```
'@Url.Action("MemberList", "Grievances", new { autocomplete = $("#autocomplete").val() })'
```

You don't need the third parameter in your URL. You'll probably get the user enter in parameter name `q` or 'term' . See documentation for it

```
public ActionResult MemberList(string q)
{
 ...
}
```

Answer to Q2

You should not return an HTML view in response to auto complete. You should return List (Array) of values as JSON instead.

```
public JsonResult MemberList(string autocomplete)
{
   var memberNames = (from p in context.Members
                   where p.MemberName.Contains(autocomplete)
                   select p.MemberName).Distinct().Take(10);
   //string content = string.Join<string>("\n", memberNames);
   return Json(memberNames.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I tried using "q" before, as it mentions it in the documentation, but that doesn't work. I tried "term" as you suggested, and that works! The Json tip also worked (just had to substitute "memberNames" for "content" in the last line, if anybody else needs to know). Thanks for your help. I would vote you up, but I don't have enough reputation yet to allow me.

Comment: Yes, you are right about `memberNames`. I updated my answer. If the answer helps you, you can mark it as accepted.